# Binding data from the list depending on the property of another control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I need to implement next UI on WPF with next logic:

I have a ViewModel:

```
public class VersionVulnerListViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Vulner> _vulners;
    public ObservableCollection<Vulner> Vulners
    {
        get
        {
            return _vulners;
        }
        private set
        {
            _vulners = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Vulners"));
        }
    }
}
```

Where Vulner have next implementation:

```
public class Vulner : PocoEntity
{
    public Vulner()
    {

    }
    // ... other properties
    public IList<VulnerData> Data { get; set; }
}
```

and VulnerData have some properties.

I need next: dependency of selected item of some combobox i need to bind diferent Data items from my list into GridView. Its will be good if its possible to do this just with XAML edetings, without adding code-behiend logic. Or add code-behiend logic, but according MVVM pattern.

Example: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but it's not answered yet, so I'll give it a try (in hope it will help somebody)

You can bind the SelectedValue of the Combobox to a variable. In the set-Block of the variable, you can also change the content of your ObservableCollection. Voilà, the GridView changes depending on the ComboBox.